# What tools do you use to make screenshots of what your software will look like after development?

Tags: user-interface, specifications

I need to write the specifications for some development on our product. The graphical aspect is very important in this development, so I need to make screenshots of what the future dialogs in the application will look like and these screenshots have to look genuine.

How would you make such screenshots without developing? Do you know of any (preferably free) tool that could do it?

Specific information: Windows 7, Developing with Visual Studio 2010 using MFC common controls mostly.

Thank you.

Comment: My colleagues use https://gomockingbird.com/

Comment: usually no-one asks for *real* screenshots, only mock-ups which you can create with photoshop and such

Comment: @alasin: usually is the word. And alas, usual is not universal.